# Will Redis lock all available db when you run `KEYS` command on a specific db?

Tags: redis, locking, database, nosql

As you now in Redis database when you run `KEYS *` command the Redis will lock database until keys return all keys.

I want to create 2 separate db in Redis and create some key in each of them ,then select one of them and run keys command on that db.

Will Redis lock all available db till answer ready or only lock selected db?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR: yes.

Redis doesn't lock - it blocks on (almost<sup>1</sup>) all commands because it is single threaded. When the server executes a command, be it a simple `GET` or the evil `KEYS`, it is busy serving it and does nothing else. The longer it takes a command to complete, the longer the server is blocked.

[`KEYS`](https://redis.io/commands/keys) is a long-running command because it **always** traverses the entire keyspace (regardless the pattern), not to mention the potentially-huge reply it makes.

That same single thread of execution also handles numbered, a.k.a. shared, databases. Any operation you perform on one of the databases blocks the entire server, all databases included. More information can be found at: https://redislabs.com/blog/benchmark-shared-vs-dedicated-redis-instances/

<sup>1</sup> [`BGSAVE`](https://redis.io/commands/bgsave), for example, is one of the few commands that do not block. As of v4, there's also [`UNLINK`](https://redis.io/commands/unlink) and more are planned to be added.